# How can I copy the project to other computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I use Visual studio 2008 to create the project. I have a problem, when I'm copy my project to other computer. When I run my project in other it have a error.

> OleDbException was unhandled by user code
>   ODBC--connection to 'SQL ServerWDT02418\SQLEXPRESS' failed

("WDT02418" is my last computer name) What is it happened? And what can I do?

I use this code to connect to Database

```
ole.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\PROJECT_WD\Database\e-OJT_Database.mdb"
myCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee", ole)
myReader =  myCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Do you have the ODBC Data Source set up on the "other" computer?

Comment: How can I check for the ODBC connect or not connect?

Comment: I use this code to connect to Database
***********
ole.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\PROJECT_WD\Database\e-OJT_Database.mdb"

myCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee", ole)

myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
**************